# SQL: Failing to bring back effective begin/end dates on order by/partition by query

Tags: sql, partition-problem, set-based

I want to bring back a result set that returns the beginning effective date and the end effective date for an id with multiple supplier changes. To do this, I am looking at a transaction table that records the id, the supplier's id and the date the transaction occurred. In cases where the id has switched suppliers, I want to retire the old association and record the new association. My intent is to insert a new row with the latest switch date as the beginning effective date and a null as the end effective date.  To complete the event, I want to update the last previous row with the end effective date populated with the latest switch date. In instances where I have a transaction, but the id hasn't switched suppliers I want to ignore the row.

What I have works for a single id, however, when I add the second id, the order/partitioning does not work.

Here is the script to generate the test rows. The sql that works for a single id is noted.

```
    -- Note: use this to emulate the known switched suppliers table

    create table #switched
    (lcard bigint);

    insert into #switched (lcard) values (700382)
    insert into #switched (lcard) values (832019)

    select * from #switched

    -- Note: this temp data represents a previously grouped/partitioned table
            --       prepped for this next phase of action

    create table #PartitionTest 
    (   FauxId int,
        lcard bigint,
        suppId int,
        switchDate datetime
    );


    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (1,700382,506,cast('Jun 23 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (2,700382,49401,cast('May 22 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (3,700382,49401,cast('May  4 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (4,700382,49401,cast('May  2 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (5,700382,49401,cast('Apr 26 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (6,700382,49401,cast('Mar 15 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (1,832019,27088,cast('Jun 18 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (2,832019,232,cast('May 24 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (3,832019,232,cast('May 23 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (4,832019,232,cast('May 22 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (5,832019,232,cast('May 21 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (6,832019,232,cast('May 17 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))
    INSERT INTO #PartitionTest (FauxId,lcard,suppId,switchDate) VALUES (7,832019,232,cast('May 16 2013 12:00AM' as datetime))

    -- Note: Order results by lcard, then order the supplier id by
        --       the transaction date found. FauxId is from the previous partitioning

    select * from #PartitionTest
     order by lcard,fauxId, suppId, switchDate

    -- This is the statement that is failing when attempting to utilize 
        -- the ids in #switched as the criterion processing sets of ids.

    ;with sifted
        as ( select *,
          row_number() over (ORDER BY switchDate) - row_number() over (PARTITION BY suppId ORDER BY switchDate) as G
        from #PartitionTest
        where lcard in
         (select lcard
            from #switched
          )
         -- // DEBUG TEST: specific card holder(s)
         -- NOTE: when both lcards are used, the beginEffDate/endEffDate goal fails
         -- and lcard in ('8320198','7003824')
         -- NOTE: this represents the intent
         and lcard in ('832019')
        ),
       refined as
         (select lcard,
                 suppId,
                MIN(switchDate) BeginEffDate,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY min(switchDate)) as OrgSplit
         from sifted
          group by lcard,suppId, G)
   select a.lcard,
          a.suppId,
          a.BeginEffDate,
          b.BeginEffDate as EndEffDate
    from refined a
          left join refined b
            on a.OrgSplit + 1 = b.OrgSplit
    order by a.lcard, a.suppId



    -- drop table #switched;
    -- drop table #PartitionTest;
```

==================================================================

## EDITED

Here are the desired results:

[image]

Comment: Your example has only a `select`.  Yet you say you want to do an `insert` and `update`.  What do you mean that it "works" for a single id?  Can you give an example of the expected output for the data you provide?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, you are right--I didn't add any inserts/updates just for the ease of looking at the select statement that would essentially drive both actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, I have the dense_rank() option rather than working with partition/over.
The solution:

```
    WITH R AS (
    SELECT
        lcard,
        suppId,
        switchDate,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY lcard ORDER BY switchDate) -
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY lcard ORDER BY suppId, switchDate) AS grp
    FROM
        #PartitionTest
    ),
    S AS (
    SELECT
        lcard,
        suppId,
        MAX(switchDate) AS dt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lcard ORDER BY MAX(switchDate)) AS rn
    FROM
        R
    GROUP BY
        lcard,
        suppId,
        grp
    )
    SELECT
        A.lcard,
        A.suppId,
        A.dt AS BeginEffDate,
        B.dt AS EndEffDate
    FROM
        S AS A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        S AS B
        ON A.lcard = B.lcard
        AND A.rn = B.rn - 1
    ORDER BY
        lcard,
        BeginEffDate
    GO
```

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do was to change a line in the `sifted` CTE to this:

```
      row_number() over (ORDER BY switchDate) - row_number() over (PARTITION BY lcard, suppId ORDER BY switchDate) as G
```

Note `lcard,` added to the PARTITION BY.

The whole statement will look like this:

```
;with sifted
    as ( select *,
      row_number() over (ORDER BY switchDate) - row_number() over (PARTITION BY lcard, suppId ORDER BY switchDate) as G
    from #PartitionTest
    where lcard in
     (select lcard
        from #switched
      )
     -- // DEBUG TEST: specific card holder(s)
     -- NOTE: when both lcards are used, the beginEffDate/endEffDate goal fails
     -- and lcard in ('8320198','7003824')
     -- NOTE: this represents the intent
     and lcard in (832019,700382)
    ),
   refined as
     (select lcard,
             suppId,
            MIN(switchDate) BeginEffDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY min(switchDate)) as OrgSplit
     from sifted
      group by lcard,suppId, G)
```

select a.lcard,
          a.suppId,
          a.BeginEffDate,
          b.BeginEffDate as EndEffDate
    from refined a
          left join refined b
            on a.OrgSplit + 1 = b.OrgSplit
    order by a.lcard, a.suppId

As soon as I saw the mixed up lcard, suppId combinations I knew where the problem was

Comment: we're getting the same result set so 70082,506,2013-06-23,null is correct--the 2 entries for 700382,49401 should be reduced to only 1: 700382,49401,2013-03-15,2013-06-23.

Comment: ...and ...832019 should be reduced to 2--832019,27088,2013-06-23,null and 832019,232,2013-05-16,2013-06-23.